# jQuery text() not working with API

Tags: jquery, api, text

Trying to use jQuery to add 4 different donation totals together. One of the totals is populated via an API.

```
<p class="donor-raised" id="api-raised"></p>
```

As you can see there's nothing to be read when I use `$("#api-raised").text()`

It doesn't say `undefined` or anything. Just, nothing.

I tried using a document.ready function to see if that was the problem. It wasn't.

If I inspect it in the browser it looks like this:

```
<p class="donor-raised" id="api-raised">$10,000</p>
```

So, I'm not really understanding why it can't read it.

Any help?

Edit, with more code

My HTML:

```
<p class="donor-raised" id="api-raised"></p>
<p class="donor-raised oe_structure">Coming Soon!</p>
<p class="donor-raised oe_structure">Coming Sooner!</p>
<p class="donor-raised oe_structure">Coming Soonest!</p>
```

My API function:   ***Is not AJAX***

```
$(function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', "https://test.site.org/get-thermo-info/company", true);
  req.send();

  req.onreadystatechange = processReq;

  function processReq(e) {
    var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    var num = response.donation_goal;
    var $total = num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    document.getElementById("api-raised").innerHTML = "$" +  $total;
  }
});
```

My Get Nums function (so far...):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var donors_raised = $(".donor-raised");
  var total = 0;

  donors_raised.each(function() {
    var donations_total = $(this).text();

    console.log("Donations: " + donations_total);
    // total += donations_total;
  })
  console.log("Total: " + total);
});
```

So, when all is said and done, I want to `parseInt()` the `.text()` and add them all together for a final total.

Comment: Could you please provide a test case?

Comment: If this field is populated via ajax, you need to check it's text after ajax loaded. So you need to use callback function called by this ajax after it's success

Comment: could you please post more code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So, I changed my API function to:

```
$.getJSON('https://test.site.org/get-thermo-info/company').done(
  function(data) {
    var num = data.donation_goal;
    var $total = num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    document.getElementById("api-raised").innerHTML = "$" +  $total;
    console.log(num, $total);
    getTotalDonations();
});
```

And changed my Get Nums function so that I call it inside the JSON function.

What was happening, was the Get Nums function was happening too early... Obvious answer!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood correctly. 
First of all `.text()` is getter
If u want add text it works `.text("required content");`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to add text. Just trying to get the text from the <p>.